# Rails default layout file ignored

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I was under the impression that if you had file named application.html.erb in your  **layouts** directory that this layout would be applied automatically to all views without having to explicitly refer to it.
This doesn't appear to be the case.

I have one 'home' controller and it has one 'index' method:

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
   def index
   end
end
```

and the related **home.html.erb** view page:

```
<h2>Welcome!</h2>
<div>Stay tuned for basic functions to start arriving on this site.</div>
<div>The site will not look very stylish until one of the bounties gets done about writing the Style guide.</div>
```

and finally the **application.html.erb** file located in layouts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Title</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a href="/categories/index">Categories</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= yield %>

<div class="footer">Michael</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above file was ignored until I added an explicit reference to the layout in my home controller like this:

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
   layout 'application'
   def index
   end
end
```

What gives? I don't want to have to name the layout I am using in every controller. That was the point of having it at the application level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are inhering from ActionController::Base. You need to subclass from ApplicationController to ask Rails to use "application" layout as the default.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end
end
```